# Regex syntax in teradata

Tags: regex, teradata

In functions like `REGEXP_REPLACE`, `REGEXP_SIMILAR` we need to mention the regular expression for matching a part of the string. Does the regex follow same syntax as that of regex in java or does Teradata have a separate syntax for regular expressions?

Comment: In my experience, it has been the same.

Comment: Afaik it's based on *Perl Compatible Regular Expressions*: http://www.pcre.org/

Comment: @dnoeth  afaik it is not mentioned in the teradata docs about which reg ex syntax it follows  .Can you give some pointers where I can find this?

Comment: Well, the PCRE syntax is the one which usually works

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as PCRE (C, Java, PHP, Javascript).

For example, let's say you have a bunch of emails and you want just the web domains from that you would use

```
SELECT RegExp_Replace(email, '^.*@(.*)', '\1', 1, 0, 'i') FROM emails;
```

You could even add the http:// to the start using the following:

```
SELECT RegExp_Replace(email, '^.*@(.*)', 'http://\1', 1, 0, 'i') FROM emails;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and since there was no satisfying answer started to investigate. According to [this](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/which-standard-is-used-for-REGEX-regular-expression-functions-in/td-p/16772) support forum answer from a Teradata employee, it is [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (ERE) flavor.

> I tried to find out what standard TD14.10 is using, I just found it is
>   ANSI SQL 2008 compliant.  Which I found have to be POSIX standard for
>   ERE.
>
> I checked other vendors (Oracle) and they have POSIX-ERE with some
>   PCRE extensions. The [:word:] is POSIX non-standard, but some
>   implementations of regexp are understanding it.