# Extract table name using SQL from a column that stores queries

Tags: sql, teradata

A table stores queries in it and I need to extract the tablename from those queries.

table:main

| ID | querytext |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | select a.record_id, a.name, b.person FROM database.atable a join database.btable b on b.id= a.id; |
| 2 | select c.record_id, c.name, d.person FROM database.ctable c join database.dtable d on c.id= d.id; |

Expected results:

```
database.atable
database.ctable
```

`SELECT SUBSTR(querytext, position('database.' in querytext), 30) FROM main;`

This almost works, but I don't know how long or short the table name could be. If it is longer than 30, it will cut off results. If shorter, it could include other parts of the query. I was reading strtok and thought about using that to get to the space after the name to stop, but couldn't quite get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this might be a good use case for [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/GawwvSb00HmeuOgDwXHNdA):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(querytext, '(<?FROM database\.)(.+?\b)', 1, 1, 'i')
```

The pattern looks for the string literal `FROM database.` that immediately precedes a tablename matching the pattern `(.+?\b)`.

Further - the pattern `(.+?\b)` matches any characters (`.`) occurring at least one time (`+`) non-greedily (`?` token) up to a word boundary character (`\b`), which judging by your sample data, should match on the whitespace immediately proceeding the table name.

You can see how this pattern is interpreted in even more detail using a utility like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qj8huu/2).

---

Further (albeit slightly tangential) reading regarding the PCRE-style RegExp support in Teradata: [Regex syntax in teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696731/regex-syntax-in-teradata)

Comment: This was a great answer. +1 for the link to Regex101 it allowed me to tweak a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Little funky-looking, but should work:

```
select 
  strtok( substr( strsql, index(strsql,'FROM ')+length('FROM '), length(strsql)), ' ', 1 ) 
from (
select 
'select c.record_id, c.name, d.person FROM database.ctable c join database.dtable d on c.id= d.id' 
  as strsql
) s1;
```

or in your case

```
select strtok( 
  substr( querytext, index(querytext,'FROM ')+length('FROM '), length(querytext)) 
  ,' ', 1 
  ) from main;
```